# ruby acts-as-taggable-on gem tag_counts_on method with tenant conditions

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, acts-as-taggable-on

Love this gem and I've studied [the source code](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/e0f859edd2c1f5d1d62f612478e11da8625e94bd/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/collection.rb#L69) but I'm stumped. I suspect I'm close but I need help finalizing this syntax. Please!!

`Pizza.tag_counts_on(:topping, {conditions: "WHERE tenant IS '1'"})` (Yup, tenant is a string!)

This syntax results in error `(Object doesn't support #inspect)` (Same error if I try a tenant as an int.)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used this gem, but can't you provide the conditions to the base class?

```
Pizza.where(tenant: '1').tag_counts_on(:topping)
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks Carl but I'm not sure if this is possible. Nor am I sure what you mean.

Comment: @GuyWrySmile - yeah sorry for the vague answer, i'll try to do better.
What i'm suggesting first filter out the records where the conditions apply and running `.tag_counts_on` that collection. Maybe that doesn't work in your case?

Here's a short reference: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#tag-cloud-calculations